# foreach iterators on multiple nodes

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I'm trying to run a simulation on a cluster of 4 nodes each with 40 cores / 80 threads and I continuously run into an OUT_OF_MEMORY error when running a parallelized foreach loop. I am pretty sure that this has to do with the fact that I am iterating the loop through the rows of a large tibble `params`.

I already tried changing `params` to a list and iterating through a list (hoping that this will be easier on the memory) but this didn't help. Also, I tried using an interator which, as far as I understand, should prevent `params` to be loaded into each thread (thus preventing the OUT_OF_MEMORY error) but this didn't work either. I suspect that this happens because I am working on multiples nodes (and I have read something like 'They don't share physical memory') but that is only my guess.

Here is how I have set up my latest try:

```
procs <- 2 * as.numeric(Sys.getenv("SLURM_NTASKS")) 
itx <- iter(params, by = 'row')

registerDoParallel(procs)
tib <- foreach (i = itx,
         .packages=c("tidyverse", "stabledist",  
                       "copula", "VineCopula", "MMDCopula", 'glue')
         ) %dopar% {
    
    # Grab the variables from each row
    alpha <- i[['alpha']]
    d <- i[['delta']]
    s <- i[['seed']]
    a <- i[['mu']] %>% unlist %>% unname
    a_name <- nameTmp(a)
    time <- i[['time']]
    copula <- i[['copula']]
    type <- i[['type']]
    
    set.seed(s)
    a_j <- rev( 1/(1 + (1:(20*TMax))^(d)) )
    X <- Simulate_Lin_Proc(alpha, TMax, a_j, 1)
    tibTmp <- f(...) # Function dependent on the parameters (returns 1 row tibble)
    
    return(tibTmp)
}
stopImplicitCluster()
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you are using slurm. Have you made sure that every task gets enough memory/is the default enough? Do you have an idea where in your simulation you have a high memory usage? Usually, parameters don't need that much space (but without knowing your data, it's hard to tell), but your approach with `iter` is definitely good.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend four potential solutions.

1. Keep each object within the iterations of the loop only as long as you need it. Remove it or overwrite it once it is no longer used.
2. Split the vector over which you loop into chunks and write each chunk's output to disk. This avoids keeping the growing list of returned values in memory.

```r
# Split params vector in chunks of 5000 elements
params_chunks <- split(params, ceiling(seq_along(params)/5000))
    
# Loop over chunks
foreach(P_C = 1:length(params_chunks), .packages=c("tidyverse", "stabledist", "copula", "VineCopula", "MMDCopula", "glue", "foreach")) %dopar% {
   p_c <- params_chunks[[P_C]]
    
   # Loop over elements within chunks
   foreach(p = p_c, .packages=c("tidyverse", "stabledist", "copula", "VineCopula", "MMDCopula", "glue")) %do% {
      ...
      return(tibTmp)
   } %>%
   saveRDS(., paste0(some_directory, P_C, ".RDS"))
   return(NULL)
}
```

Instead of writing the intermediate list output as RDS files to disk, you could also row-bind them and write them as feather files to disk. It depends on the structure of the returned `tibTmp` whether RDS or feather files are more efficient.

3. How does the server handle this process outside R? Does it use Openmpi? If yes, I recommend to use `doMPI` instead of `doParallel`. That lets the outside Openmpi process, which is tailored to the cluster server and has more control over it, handle the parallelization rather than controlling it from inside R.

That means that instead of loading the `doParallel` package, you post the following code into your R script:

```r
if (!is.loaded("mpi_initialize")) {
   library("doMPI")
}

cl <- startMPIcluster(comm=0)
registerDoMPI(cl)
  
.Last <- function(){
   if (is.loaded("mpi_initialize")){
      if (mpi.comm.size(1) > 0){
         mpi.close.Rslaves()
      }
      .Call("mpi_finalize")
   }
}
```

And at the bottom of the script you mention:

```r
closeCluster(cl)
mpi.quit()
```

4. You can also restrict the number of tasks per node. In SLURM job files you can set this with the `--tasks-per-node` option. E.g. the line `#SBATCH --tasks-per-node=16` sets the maximum number of tasks per node to 16. Keep reducing the number of nodes until the computations fit into the node's physical memory.

Comment: I tried deleting variables after computation already but calling rm() and gc() didn't yield any results. As for your third approach: After trying for hours to get openmpi to work I gave up on that approach. Somehow I am not able to call the script after your suggested changes properly on SLURM, so it never works out.

As for your second approach I implemented it now (there are two closing paranthesis missing before each %do% / %dopar%) and hopefully it will work. So far it is still running on a development node and hasn't thrown OUT_OF_MEMORY yet.

Comment: I didn't get an OUT_OF_MEMORY error but somehow only one row of params was evaluated (at least that's what has been saved to disk).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing parentheses, which I now fixed. Regarding the third approach: did you install `doMPI` and `Rmpi`? Did you post the first chunk of code at the top of your R script? What does the line of code in your job script executing the R script look like? Regarding the second approach: that fact that your R script only writes one file to disk is related to some other error in your code. Could you paste your R script here (e.g. by extending your question)?